# How to get a single field in a VIEW to use in WHERE

Tags: mysql, view, field, where-clause

Hello dear stack overflow friends,

I want to use a single field located in an other view as a parameter for a WHERE clause (in an other view). However, I can't find the correct way to get this done.

I already used the FIRST() function, but this gives a syntax error.

This probably has to do with the fact that it selects the first row in its whole, but I want to get only a single field in this row. (actually this whole view only has one field)

```
/*this first view contains the value to use for the second view, called average */
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW getAverage AS
SELECT AVG(todoitem.completiondate-todoitem.creationdate) as average from todolist
inner join todoitem on todoitem.id=todolist.id;

/*this view has a WHERE clause that should use a value in the getAverage VIEW */
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW aboveAverage AS
SELECT * FROM todolist
inner join todoitem on todoitem.id=todolist.id
WHERE (todoitem.completiondate-todoitem.creationdate > FIRST(getAverage.average));
```

If somebody could help me I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW aboveAverage AS
    SELECT *
    FROM todolist inner join
         todoitem
         on todoitem.id=todolist.id
    WHERE (todoitem.completiondate-todoitem.creationdate > (SELECT average FROM getAverage);
```

MySQL does allow subqueries in the `where` and `select` clauses.  You wouldn't need the second view for this.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I want. Though somehow I now get an error that the view contains a double 'id' column. Do you have any idea how this is possible, as I think I merged those 2 columns? If I select something as only 'name' instead of * it works great.

Comment: @Gaargod . . . It is good practice to list all the columns explicitly instead of using `*`.  A quick-and-dirty approach is to use `using` instead of `on`.